# Photoshop - JPEG Image Option - Difference in Quality

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, jpeg

In Photoshop, while saving an image as JPEG, there is an **Image Option** called **Quality**.

Increasing or decreasing the value, only increases or reduces the size of the JPEG file.

If we try to zoom in the images saved in different quality values, there is no difference.

Then why there is Quality option? What is the real use and need of this option?

Comment: Take two qualities as different layers, chose difference, then adjust contrast and have a look

Comment: Make sure you are looking at the saved images *after* you close your original image.  You'll see the difference, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say *"if we try to zoom in the images saved in different quality values, there is no difference"*, but, actually, that's just because you're not looking closely enough, or don't know what to look for. If you choose an extreme value (very low) the difference should be obvious. At higher settings, it's more tricky, but usually there's a difference there too even if it's harder to detect by eye.

Take a look at [What are jpeg artifacts and what can be done about them?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19270/what-are-jpeg-artifacts-and-what-can-be-done-about-them) for the *result* of JPEG compression, which will be more apparent at lower quality levels, and [Is it worth using Pentax's Premium JPEG quality setting?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21690/pentax-k-5-is-it-worth-using-the-premium-jpeg-quality-setting/) for some additional examples.