# Is there a meaningful image quality difference between the Canon Powershot SX410 vs SX510?

Tags: canon, image-quality, megapixels, powershot

Can you show me a picture difference between the Canon Powershot SX410 and the Powershot SX510? Is there a noticeable difference between 12 megapixel and 20 megapixel here? I want to buy one of these models, but I don't want to buy the wrong one.

Comment: What size prints do you usually make?

Comment: Quality can be subjective and dependant upon your individual requirements. On Paper and specs alone,the 510 is the updated model and as a result, is techincally capable of producing better quality and larger images. Being only 12MP, the SX410 has a higher Pixel Density, and to some, that may actually mean, a better quality picture but then again, SX510 has a hight Pixel Pitch, and to some, that would yield a better image. if I was not printing, I would stick to the SX410

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do megapixels matter with modern sensor technology?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14773/do-megapixels-matter-with-modern-sensor-technology)