# Does MP influence ISO?

Tags: image-quality, iso, sony-nex

I use [Sony Nex 6](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/sony-alpha-nex-6) and I noticed that on not really high ISO (let's say 1600) pictures get discernibly grainy. Also I know that the [next's model](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/sonynex7) main feature is larger image size (24MP comparing to 16MP on Nex-6).

So I'm trying to wrap my head around if larger image size may result in better ISO sensitivity (so images get less grainy)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do megapixels matter with modern sensor technology?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14773/do-megapixels-matter-with-modern-sensor-technology)

Answer (score 2):

> So I'm trying to wrap my head around if larger image size may result in better ISO sensitivity (so images get less grainy)?

It actually tends to work the other way: larger photosites give better low-light performance because each site has more photons falling on it.

So if you have two sensors with the same physical dimensions, the one with the *lower* pixel count will generally yield a less noisy (but lower resolution) image. Or, if you have two sensors with the same pixel count but different physical dimensions (e.g. APS-C and full frame), the larger sensor will offer better low-light performance.

The numbers for those two models bears this out. Your NEX-6 offers ISO settings all the way up to 25600, while the NEX-7 only goes up to ISO 16000.

Comment: " larger photosites give better low-light performance because each site has more photons falling on it. " - I'd say that it occurs because of increased fill rate, not because of photon number per pixel increase.

Comment: It's also worth to mention that cameras with high MP count get better dynamic range at base ISO as higher MP count helps to overcome current 14bit ADC limitation.

Comment: It's also worth noting that it's not just pixel size, but that improvements in sensor design / manufacture also come into play - newer sensors are more likely to outperform older ones even with a larger pixel.

Comment: @PinhollowEuri It occurs because the increased numbers of photons striking each pixel well allow a lower noise floor, which is pretty much the same thing as saying increased dynamic range. The larger surface area also reduces photon shot noise by averaging the randomness more on a per-pixel level.

Comment: Larger sensor size gives less grainy images because it has more sensitive elements which consume photons thus result in a more dynamic image range. If we continue speaking about Sony Nex 6 and 7 models AFAIU because Nex-7 model sensor size remains the same the larger image size (24MP) is achieved due to pure scaling like digital zooming?