# Why picture quality decreasing with very big apperture?

Tags: image-quality, optical-quality

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is a “diffraction limit”?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8304/what-is-a-diffraction-limit)
>   [Why are my photos taken at f/11 less sharp than those taken at a wider aperture?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20430/why-are-my-photos-taken-at-f-11-less-sharp-than-those-taken-at-a-wider-aperture)

I have made 3 landscape pictures with f/12, f/22 and f/32. Shutter speed and ISO are almost same, but last one has a lot of blur and is very pale.
Why this happen?
My purpose was to get maximal DOF.

Details: Nikon d5100, 18-55 kit

Comment: If you provide the pictures, it might be easier to diagnose what is happening.

Comment: You are very confused, see the question as suggested duplicate. F/22 is a very small aperture and causes your camera to pass beyond its diffraction limit, causing everything to become blurry. There should be very little reason to shoot beyond F/11 with such a DSLR. If you need longer shutter-speeds, use a quality ND filter.

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20430/why-are-my-photos-taken-at-f-11-less-sharp-than-those-taken-at-a-wider-aperture

Comment: FYI: for the Nikon D5100 + 18-55mm kit lens, the lens only goes up to f22.

Comment: Also if your aperture changes, your shutter speed / ISO should change to maintain the same exposure (Assuming that you are not in manual mode). Did you use a tripod?

Comment: @Itai My purpose was to get maximal DOF possible with my camera, not shutter speed... So you suggest to use F/12 as limit for my aperture and DOF?

Comment: @Vivek 
for 18mm max is 22
but for 55m it is 36

Yes I have used tripod and was in manual mode

Comment: Oh yes. F/13 actually should be the diffraction limit for your camera. Beyond that, everything gets blurry.

Comment: @drewbenn yes, I understood these factors. But blurry image with big F number seems invariant on all pictures, with small ISO~250 and speed 1/400. So I it seems diffraction limit really matters

Comment: Another point to remember is that a very big aperture is one that has a small number. F/1.4 is very very big aperture, F/22 is a tiny aperture, not the other way round. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without wishing to get into detail - the short answer to your question is diffraction.  This happens at smaller apertures, usually when you get above f/16 to f/22 etc, and the extent to which it occurs depends on the optical quality of the lens used.  In your case, the 18-55mm kit lens which is a mass-produced cheap kit lens will show this problem moreso than say a fixed focal length prime lens.

You can achieve good depth of field with a more modest aperture such as f/14. There is rarely if ever good cause to go all the way up to f/22.