# Why are my new camera's photos coming out blurrier than my iPhone's when I look at them zoomed in?

Tags: sharpness

I am a beginner at photography and recently got a camera (Nikon D5600). I watched a few videos on how to use it but I am still finding it difficult to operate. I have several questions but the main one is how to make pictures sharper?

I have an iPhone X which takes better pictures, when I zoom in I can see the image clearly, however when I zoom in on a photo with my camera, everything is kind of blurry. The photos I’m using as comparison are the ones from the SnapBridge app.

Does anyone have any tips on how to learn the best way to take pictures or how to at least make my pictures a higher resolution?

This is the image from my iPhone:

[image: Picture from iPhone]

This is the image from my D5600 and 18-55 kit lens @28mm:

Settings:
M mode, ISO 800, 1/200s, f/13, shooting RAW+jpeg.

[image: Picture from Nikon D5600]

Comment: What are the two example photos? Is the first from your iPhone and the second from your Nikon? Are these even photos you took, or are these photos you want to emulate? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Part of the explanation is likely in the camera settings; so  posting the pictures with the EXIF data left in them is somewhat required. If you don't want to post the full-size picture, a crop left at 100% size of the same part of both pictures will also allow comparisons that aren't skewed by the scaling process.

Comment: 1. imgur strips out metadata, so the settings can't be obtained from the images.  You'll have to explicitly include them with your question.  2. A relevant setting is F-stop.  Smaller F-number = larger aperture = shallow DOF = less in focus.  High F-number = smaller aperture = deep DOF, but diffraction = more in "focus", but looks blurry. 3. You are using a DSLR.  Focus calibration could be off.  Try live view to see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: Basically, the first photo is taken by the iPhone X and the second with the camera. When looking at the photos on my phone, I can see that the photos taken with the iPhone have a higher resolution, I am wondering how to make camera photos sharper and less blurry?

Comment: I am very new to these terminologies and I am trying to study it properly, I will attempt to add a photo of the settings used for the photo taken by the camera

Comment: Overall, i am looking for some sort of accurate tutorial on how to understand what settings are most appropriate for any given environment setting. Also I cant seem to take a HQ picture that is blurred

Comment: Your iPhone has 12 megapixels and your Nikon has 24 megapixels, so in theory the latter is capable of appearing better than the former, the opposite of what you are describing.  But as all the above comments point out, the question is missing the most significant information that's required for this to be answered: what the cameras were set to when the photos were taken?

Comment: I have added photos above with the settings of the photo at the time when the picture was taken

Comment: Perhaps you're running in to depth of field issues. Small-sensor cameras like your phone camera have a much wider depth of field [DOF] (more stuff in focus) than the larger sensor in your DSLR which will have a narrower DOF (less stuff in focus). This will be clearly evident in your example shots.

Comment: What lens did you get with the D5600? These days, when going up against a quality smartphone, you are going up against a fast aspheric wideangle. Which tends to be NOT the kind of lens included in an entry level DSLR kit.

Comment: @rackandboneman, the OP added that information in image form, and I removed it in an edit. reinstated it; an 18-55 kit was used.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're seeing (if you're judging the sharpness by the light-in-the-tunnel area of the frame) is the difference in depth of field between a small sensor with a very short lens and a big sensor with a longer one.

If you look at the ivy along the sides, both shots are pretty dang sharp. Also, at f/13, you're past the [diffraction limit](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8304/what-is-a-diffraction-limit), which could be taking an edge off your sharpness.  But it may also be about where you focused in the scene. If you focused on the objects closest to you, you were limiting the DoF at the far end.

Your iPhone is using a sensor that's basically got a 6x crop factor. It's using a proportionately 6x shorter lens. That extends its depth of field out, even if you're focusing closer, and can still encompass infinity to get everything in focus.

See also: [Why are my photos not crisp?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/why-are-my-photos-not-crisp)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you are seeing as *clear vs blurry*. The small images provided are less than ideal for analysis, plus the downsized images bring into question the scaling techniques used.

Given the images available, the phone image is a wider angle shot. Both images have slightly different perspectives and lighting, as well as different lens aberrations.

In order to get something a little closer to 1-1 comparison, I cropped the Phone image to the same angular view, and scaled the D5600 image to 70% to get the best match I could.

**Cropped Phone Image**
[image]

**70% Scaled D5600 Image**
[image]

The Phone image is darker and higher contrast but I'm not seeing the "*Blurry*" you referred to.