# How many blades does my lens' aperture diaphragm have when I get 12-pointed starbursts?

Tags: aperture, canon-550d, optics

**[Here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/9597/64)** I figured that my camera has either three or six blades.

But yesterday I took another shot at night with the same setup which has twelve srokes:

[image]

The camera is a [Canon 550D](http://www.canon.co.uk/for_home/product_finder/cameras/digital_slr/EOS_550D/index.aspx?specs=1) and I used the same 18-135 lens for both the shots.

Is this possible with 3 or 6 blades?

Comment: You haven't linked to the image properly...

Comment: I see the image put correctly in the question.. this is the [direct link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MPvWD.jpg).

Comment: The only links in the question are 'here' to the other question and the link to the 550D - it just says 'enter image description here' with no link'. Your direct link goes to a 404 error, so that's probably the issue.

Comment: @ElindilTheTall: No, it does not.. I just checked again.. it links to an image.

Comment: The address is http://i.stack.imgur.com/MPvWD.jpg , but it just results in a 404 for me...

Comment: Bingo, now it works

Comment: Three blade (triangular) apertures are extremely rare, you'd know if you had one from the weird bokeh!

Comment: This question is asked (implicitly) and answered at http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/6605

Comment: @Lazer Hi - any chance of accepting my answer to this question? I'd really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 12):

Yours has 6 blades. There are a few ways of finding out for sure:

1. Look at the shape of light bursts or [bokeh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bokeh) in pictures. I can see how your image above is a bit confusing but it's actually 6 shapes (each with two "outer lines") rather than 12. Likewise, the shape of the bokeh in [this shot](http://www.flickr.com/photos/cholden/2107581320/) clearly shows it was taken with a 7-blade lens. However, that won't always work: it depends on the aperture the shot was taken with, and some lenses have more curved blades that lead to very round bokeh.
2. Look at the lens. As others have pointed out, the aperture blades are in the lens, not the camera body. Normally the camera keeps the aperture wide open (regardless of the setting you may have chosen) until you actually press the shutter: this is to let plenty of light through the lens while you're composing and focusing your shot. However, your camera has a button that forces the aperture to close to the currently set value and lets you see the blades very clearly. On a Canon it's a small round button, positioned just below the lens release button (you can see it on the bottom right image [here](http://a.img-dpreview.com/previews/CanonEOS550D/images/allroundview.jpg)). So, to see the aperture blades for yourself:

   - Set the camera into AV mode and select a reasonably narrow aperture (f/8 will do fine).
   - Look into the front of the lens.
   - Press that button! See the blades?
3. Find the lens specifications online. You'll find a spec for most lenses and that should tell you how many blades it has. I searched for "canon 18 135" and the [Canon specification page](http://www.canon.co.uk/For_Home/Product_Finder/Cameras/EF_Lenses/Standard_Zoom/EF-S_18-135mm_f3.5-5.6_IS/) came up in my Google results. As we suspected: 6 blades.

Comment: Important part of this answer (mainly for understanding of how a DSLR works): "Look at the lens. As others have pointed out, the aperture blades are in the lens, not the camera body."

Answer (score 1):

It's not your camera that has blades, the aperture diaphragm (located in lens) has them. With different lenses, your camera will have different number of aperture blades.

Comment: I used the same lens both times!

Answer (score 1):

The Canon 18-135 lens has 6 circular aperture blades.

Comment: "If you give a person a fish....."

Comment: Eh, the linked question already had a clear explanation beyond that.  You can't teach a man to fish very well via this website.