# What causes these "striped" streaks from light sources?

Tags: troubleshooting, artifacts

About 10 days ago I took this photo with a Samsung G S3 [image]

and why do those lights appear as eh.. eh... stripes?? Just like there was a star filter but lacking the stripe which is perpendicular to the stripe..?
And I found [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/76821/what-causes-these-streaked-rays-from-light-sources) but it's about a lens flare thing..
I thought my problem is about the aperture or something... But anyway, are that question and my question about the same problem?

Comment: looks like a greasy front lens that one tried (and fail) to clean... Just my 2 cents

Comment: Did you check the front element of your lens? Is it clean?

Answer (score 3):

Yes — it looks the same to me. Likely to be caused by a smear on the front of your lens (or on a protective covering of some type). In fact, it's so similar I've marked this as a duplicate of the previous questions, as there's no real point in explaining the details twice.