# What explains a lens flare "streak" on only one side of light source?

Tags: optics, artifacts, lens-flare

We know than [an axial streak can be caused by a smudged lens that has been wiped in one direction](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/80462/27832).  The following image shows both lens flare and a lens "streak."
[image: Sunset with lens flare and lens streak]

But what could explain the *one-sided* streak in the following picture?  I.e., why doesn't it flare/streak to *both* sides of the sun?  (It was taken shortly after the first image above, by the same iPhone XS.)
[image: Half-streak]

Comment: looks like lens-has-been-wiped-recently effect, but as you say, one-sided.  Only observation I can make is that it's a different angle to the previous so between the two photo's it must have had a fresh wipe or fingerprint on it...  maybe only over half the lens.

Comment: @5Diraptor [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655/15871) and [Criteria for determining if a post should be a comment or an answer](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5578/15871)

Answer (score 1):

As you already suspected, it is most probably a partially smudged lens on that phone. It might also be a fingerprint just covering part of the lens. With tiny lenses, even the space between the ridges of a fingerprint can cause interesting effects.

You already had the right link there:
[What causes lens flare along specific axes?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/80453/what-causes-lens-flare-along-specific-axes/80462#80462)