# Help with lights in photos

Tags: lighting, photo-editing, light

first, I apologize for the writing of this post, since I do not speak English and I am still learning it

My photos come out this way, I think it is the lens that is dirty, but I am not sure, I would like to ask you if you could tell me how to correct this for future photos, and how to edit the photograph so that at least one photo looks good
(It is not the original, it is cropped because it weighs a lot)

Hola, primero que nada, me disculpo por la redacción de este post, ya que no hablo inglés y aún lo sigo aprendiendo

Mis fotos salen de esta manera, creo que es la lente que está sucia, pero no estoy seguro, me gustaría pedirles si me podrían informar sobre como corregir esto para futuras fotos, y como editar la fotografía para que al menos se vea bien una foto
(No es la original, esta recortada porque pesa mucho)

[image]

Comment: Hello Adán, can you give us details about your camera?  What camera model are you using?  What lens was used for this photo?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [What causes these streaked rays from light sources?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/76821)

Comment: Yeah, mi camera is sony cyber-shot DCS-H5

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/76821/what-causes-these-streaked-rays-from-light-sources

Answer (score 2):

You have a dirty lens. I would suggest following this page or searching for 'how to clean camera lens'
https://www.bhphotovideo.com/explora/photography/tips-and-solutions/how-to-clean-your-lens-and-filters

You may also have a 'rear smudge' if the lens itself is removable- accidentally putting your thumb on the back of the lens may cause this too.

More aggressive cleaning might be necessary if this does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your lens has an oily substance spread evenly over most of its surface. The most likely culprit is skin oil from finger prints that was then smeared around without being removed by an attempt to clean the lens with a dry cloth.

It's also possible to get this effect by using a cloth that has oil from a previous use on the cloth to spread the oily substance all over the lens.¹

The way to get rid of it is the same as the way to clean a lens any time *wet cleaning* is required:

- Use a blower or brush first to knock off any loose dirt and dust that might scratch the lens coating if rubbed between the lens and a cleaning cloth, pad, or tissue.
- Use a clean, dry cloth that won't leave lint behind. Microfiber cloths in sizes convenient for cleaning optical surfaces are readily available from sellers of camera equipment. You can also use a disposable  product that won't scratch your lens such as a Pec*Pad or a piece of lens cleaning tissue instead.
- Put a few drops of lens cleaning fluid *on the cloth, disposable pad, or lens cleaning tissue* (NOT directly on the lens).
- Move the wet spot on the cloth against the lens in a circular motion beginning in the center of the lens and continuing in a spiral pattern out to the edge of the lens.
- Dry the lens with a part of the cloth, pad, or dry piece of lens cleaning tissue, that does not have lens cleaning fluid on it. Move in the same circular motion spiraling from the center to the edge of the lens.

You can check the results by holding the lens in such a way that a large light source at distance from the lens is reflected over the entire surface of the lens as seen with your eye(s). The surface of the glass should appear uniform and clear. If it still looks a little "foggy", you may need to repeat the cleaning with a new cloth, pad, or lens tissue. If your cloth is large enough, you could also use other parts of the cloth that have not been contaminated by the first cleaning.

Note: Be sure to wiggle the lens around a bit when inspecting it. Otherwise you can sometimes mistake reflections of smaller, bright light sources as dust or stains on the surface of the lens. Reflections will move around the surface of the lens as you wiggle the lens. Stains and dust will stay on the same spot on the lens' surface.

<sub>¹ This is why I usually carry at least two cloths in my camera bag. One for cleaning lenses and another for cleaning everything else on the camera, such as nose smudges on the camera's rear LCD. If I use the cloth that has absorbed very much skin oil from cleaning other parts of the camera, it will smear that oil all over the surface of the lens! I always fold the lens cloth the same way and try to handle it only from the "back side" (if the cloth has a tag/label, I designate the side with the tag/label as the "back" side and the other side the "front" side. When folding the cloth I always make the first fold so that the "front" side is to the inside and the "back" side to the outside.</sub>